# trying do analysis to my data in json format. my code below so far my questions is how can I join all my data , pls help I am new to python

Tags: python, json

this is what I am done so far

```
import os, json
import pandas as pd

path_to_json = 'C:\\Users\\Mohammed Al kinoon\\Desktop\\Research Data\\VCDB-master\\VCDB-master\\data\\json\\validated'

json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
print(json_files)
```

output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prjld.png)

Comment: is there a way I can read my data easily

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put it in a format the complier can read it;

```
       import json 

#open the file
with open('filepathhere') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

#reading file
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For pandas, I recommend the following:

```py
data_frames = [pd.read_json(file) for file in json_files]

combined_df = pd.concat(data_frames).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This assumes all of the files follow the same format (columns/keys) and can fit in memory. If they follow different formats, you should separate them out into groups that do follow the same format.

If they are too large to fit in memory, I recommend using Spark/pyspark.